# Microsoft Reporting Server Chart x-axis question

Tags: reporting-services

I have a simple chart, and on the x-axis I have numbers ranging from 10000 to 10031.
The numbers are from a SQL call, and these values have values, which are plotted on the y-axis, just a simple chart.
The chart is only showing six of the numbers between 10000 and 10031, and having the user figure out the other numbers, I suppose to avoid clutter.
I would like all of the x-axis number to show up, and to fit it will need to be rotated 90 degrees. 
I cannot find a setting to make all of the numbers show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In "Axis Properties", select "Axis Options" and put in "1" for the expression to show all. "2" will show every other, and the default, "0" will mean for Reporting Services to optimize as it sees fit, usually between every fourth or sixth element.